# Why aren't my jQuery click events being called when triggered from inside of an update panel (ASP.NET Web Forms)?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel, microsoft-edge

I'm working on tracking down an elusive bug in IE11 and Edge. I've noticed a difference in the network calls between Chrome and Edge, and I'm not sure if that's just a difference between the way the browsers' dev tools display traffic or if it's indicative that something is actually happening in Edge that isn't in Chrome.

The following screenshot is from dev tools in Edge, recorded during page load.
[image: Networks tab in Edge shows login request]

It looks like some request to the server is not considered authenticated, so it's being redirected to the login page. The same page load sequence in Chrome does not show that - it just has the one page request. My first question is - *is there a way to track down which thing is making that particular request using the Edge dev tools? Or is this something I need to worry about at all, if it's expected behavior?*

### Some background on the bug I'm trying to resolve

The page uses UpdatePanels and jQuery ajax both to make requests to the server. The relevant jQuery ajax calls are made in click events triggered on objects inside the update panels. I've verified that those click events aren't triggering a postback. The click handlers seem to be executing just fine (most of the time), but the bug is that sometimes they don't seem to be executed at all - none of my console.log statements appear in the console, and nothing happens (except the page jumps a little) until you click again. Every other click seems to work. It seems to happen when there is a *lot* of data loaded on the page (note the load time for the first request in dev tools).

I've made sure to rebind the click events that are on the objects inside the update panels after each update panel postback using

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest
```

The site uses forms authentication. There is just one server on the site I'm testing on - no load balancer involved.

Also - before anyone suggests it - we are trying to move away from the update panels, but we're not quite ready to retire this page which relies heavily on them. That would be my preferred solution, too :)

Comment: Are there controls within the `UpdatePanel`that trigger a postback (because they must)?

Comment: @pfx There are. I'm pretty sure they're not triggered during the click(s) in question though.  Might other controls that have postback triggers interfere with my jQuery click events? Maybe there is something in Microsoft Ajax that could interfere with other jQuery events, especially on IE/Edge.

Comment: Try this: click such a postback-trigger-control and afterwards a jQuery-non-postback-control and see if the last one still works.

Comment: @pfx If I do that, about half of the time, the very first click doesn't work (reproducing the bug I mentioned) but subsequent clicks do. The other half of the time it works just fine. I wonder if there's a race condition that's making the cause trickier to track down. For instance, when I've opened dev tools while I tested, I haven't been able to reproduce it at all.

Comment: Then the rebind after postback is fine. Is it a large page? Could it be that you do the first click before the javascript onload has completed, meaning that the jQuery click handlers have not been set yet?

Comment: @pfx That's very possible, and would make a lot of sense. It is a large page, and the largeness of the page seems to correlate with how often the issue appears. Sounds like I need to think of a way to either prevent someone from clicking on that link until the onload is complete, or provide a warning indicator that bad things will happen if they try to click before it's ready. Do you want to add an answer and I can accept it? Thanks so much for your help! I've been going around in circles with this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention that the webpage concerned is large.
Because of this, the JavaScript onload will not always have been completed yet when you do a quick first click on such a clientside hyperlink/button, which means that a regular http GET request gets triggered, which you see in the developer tools.
You will also see this in other browsers.

Try to find a way to disable these clientside hyperlinks/buttons before the onload has finished.

You could disable them initially via:

```
<a class="clientsideButton" href="#" onclick="javascript:return false">click here</a>
```

And enable them afterwards.
Don't forget to also re-bind them again after a partial postback!

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".clientsideButton").on("click", 
        function() { 
            // Make AJAX request.
    });
});
</script>
```